# findOneReplace replacment issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find a document in my db and replace it with a document that has a new name and new key.

Here is my Schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const vampireSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  title: String,
  hair_color: {type: String, default: "blonde" },
  eye_color: String,
  dob: Date,
  loves: [String],
  location: String,
  gender: String,
  victims: {type: Number, min: 0}

});

const Vampire = mongoose.model("Vampire", vampireSchema);

module.exports = Vampire;
```

Here is my executable code

```
Vampire.findOneAndReplace( { name: "Claudia" }, { name: "Eve", portrayed_by: "Tilda Swinton" }, (err, vamp) => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  else{
    console.log(vamp)
  }
  db.close()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that I can see.

First, you should pass null as the third argument in your findOneAndReplace call. This will set the options to null and should get your code running. This is in my opinion a strange behavior of mongoose.

```
Vampire.findOneAndReplace( 
        { name: "Claudia" }, 
        { name: "Eve", portrayed_by: "Tilda Swinton" }, 
        null, 
        (err, vamp) => 
{
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  else{
    console.log(vamp)
  }
  db.close()
})
```

Secondly, I would recommend adding the portrayed_by to the schema, otherwise, that field will not be in the newly created document. Therefore, I would adjust your schema that way:

```
const vampireSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  title: String,
  hair_color: {type: String, default: "blonde" },
  eye_color: String,
  dob: Date,
  loves: [String],
  location: String,
  gender: String,
  victims: {type: Number, min: 0},
  portrayed_by: String
});
```

Comment: OH haha, thanks I really appreciate it. I didn't add portayed_by into the schema because from what I read MongoDB allows anything to be passed in but I guess I need to clarify when using mongoose.

Comment: @Saifalushi, yes, Mongoose is a bit more strict with its schema and therefore this is a common pitfall. Happy, that I could help!